# Any free and current solutions that allows me to mount Google Drive in Finder?

Tags: finder, filesystem, google-apps

Are there any free and current(ly supported) solutions that allows me to mount Google Drive in Finder? I have found several OS X Fuse-based solutions on Github but most (all?) of them seem to have not been updated for several years.

Comment: @Joonas I have Backup and Sync installed. How do you mount a GD-volume in Finder from that?

Comment: @Joonas I want the drive to show up in /Volumes/Google Drive (or something like that) and then be displayed as a remote server volume in the sidebar of the Finder.

Comment: @Joonas If you don't know, maybe you should be a bit more humble? Devices listed under /Volumes usually don't use up space on your internal hard drive. Furthermore, you have direct access to files stored there (as opposed to a "sync folder" where you can only manipulate the local copy of the file).

Comment: @Joonas FYI, there are several projects on Github that offers that functionality. Problem is that few of them seem to be stable/supported.

Answer (score 1):

Probably obsolete by now but the new Google Drive for Desktop app offers that, under the streaming option.